# iOS UIImagePickerController and UIWebView cause memory issues; how do I retain my app's state when presenting these views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have instances where I'm using UIImagePickerController and UIWebView within my app, presenting them as modal view controllers from the root controller of the app. A good portion of the time, though, these cause memory warnings, which then causes my "normal" views (the current UI of the app) to be released and subsequently re-allocated when the modal view finishes. The result is, for example, that the user will choose the "image picker" and take a picture with the camera, but then press "okay" and be returned to an application which has returned to something like the booting state (and thus forgotten how to handle the image which was returned). It does not happen 100% of the time (or even 50%), but enough to be a big problem.

My question is: is there any way I can prevent this from happening, essentially temporarily reducing my memory footprint while these modal views are being displayed so that this problem does not occur?

It is very frustrating because once the UIImagePickerController modal is up, I have very little control over the app... and the memory warning happens when the image is being returned, so I don't get the chance to handle the problem. So far, I have tried removing all my views from the root view while the modal is up, etc., with little luck :(

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very obvious to every one, even i also facing the issue. The actual problem is in the iPhone ImagePickerController Camera... Apple may know this issue and may be trying to resolve this issue... Apart from that what we can do is to follow memory management rules.

http://www.slideshare.net/whalec1/ios-memory-management-basis

is a good tutorial to be followed.

I used below code for managing memory in my application... it is useful for me for some extent but not able to cure it completely.

```
   -(void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application 
    {

        NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *diskCachePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ImageCache"];
        if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:diskCachePath])
        {
            NSError *error=nil;
            NSArray *files = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:diskCachePath 
                                                          error:&error];
            if(!error)
            {
                for(NSString *file in files) {
                    [manager removeItemAtPath:[diskCachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]
                                        error:nil];

                }
            }
        }


        int i=0;
        for(id controller in self.tabBarController.viewControllers)
        {
            if(i==presentTabIndex)
            {
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            if([controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
            {
                UINavigationController *aController = (UINavigationController *)controller;
                [aController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }
            else if([controller isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
            {
                UIViewController *aController = (UIViewController *)controller;
                [aController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }

            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting example; I see that you're manually releasing cached images to help with the crappy camera problem. Very nice. I implemented the code; we will see how it goes.